# How to open port for docker container?

Tags: docker, port

I have a database on production (real os). And have docker-container with webserver and cgi (running on the same server).

And I cant get access to production database from container.
How to open port (for example 3306) and make it visible in container?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to pass the host machine's IP address to the container using the following approach:

```
docker run --add-host dockerhost:`/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print  $3}'` [my container]
```

This will add a host with the name `dockerhost` to your container. You can then access the database running on the host via `dockerhost:3306`

Comment: Command `/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print  $3}'` return ip of my router. And dockerhost links to router instead of my current machine.

Comment: You're right, sorry. The `/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3}'` command is meant to be run from the container itself. Are you running the machine in AWS, Google Cloud or somewhere else?

Comment: I want to run container on local machine and Google Cloud.